# PHP Multidimensional sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [Baritone Horn] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Maintenance
                    [Order] => 12
                    [CategoryID] => 13849839018
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Mouthpieces
                    [Order] => 13
                    [CategoryID] => 13850963018
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Accessories
                    [Order] => 11
                    [CategoryID] => 13850964018
                )

        ) 

    [Alpen Horn] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Maintenance
                    [Order] => 12
                    [CategoryID] => 13849839018
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Mouthpieces
                    [Order] => 13
                    [CategoryID] => 13850963018
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Accessories
                    [Order] => 11
                    [CategoryID] => 13850964018
                )

        ) 
)
```

I want to:

1. Sort my array so that the array is ordered alphabetically like "Alpen Horn" then "Baritone Horn".  This can be acheived using ksort but there may be a better way after considering my second point.
2. Sort each of the child arrays alphabetically so that each of the child arrays are sorted by [Name].

I know I need to use usort but my experiments so far have been uneventful.

Below is what I want to output:

```
Array
(
    [Alpen Horn] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Accessories
                    [Order] => 11
                    [CategoryID] => 13850964018
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Maintenance
                    [Order] => 12
                    [CategoryID] => 13849839018
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Mouthpieces
                    [Order] => 13
                    [CategoryID] => 13850963018
                )

        ) 

    [Baritone Horn] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Accessories
                    [Order] => 11
                    [CategoryID] => 13850964018
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Maintenance
                    [Order] => 12
                    [CategoryID] => 13849839018
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Mouthpieces
                    [Order] => 13
                    [CategoryID] => 13850963018
                )

        ) 


)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function: [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to achieve it.

Syntax:

```
bool array_multisort ( array &$array1 [, mixed $array1_sort_order = SORT_ASC
                       [, mixed $array1_sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR
                       [, mixed $... ]]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_multisort` example:

```
$array = array
(
    [Baritone Horn] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Maintenance
                    [Order] => 12
                    [CategoryID] => 13849839018
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Mouthpieces
                    [Order] => 13
                    [CategoryID] => 13850963018
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Accessories
                    [Order] => 11
                    [CategoryID] => 13850964018
                )

        ) 

    [Alpen Horn] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Maintenance
                    [Order] => 12
                    [CategoryID] => 13849839018
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Baritone Mouthpieces
                    [Order] => 13
                    [CategoryID] => 13850963018
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Accessories
                    [Order] => 11
                    [CategoryID] => 13850964018
                )

        ) 
)

$array = array_multisort($array);
```